# Set the WPF DataGrid Column.Header from DataColumn.Caption

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I am using a `DataGrid` to show contents of a `DataTable` which I build dynamically. This shows the `DataColumn.ColumnName` in the DataGrid Column Header by default.

I am trying to replace the column headings and hide some columns in the UserControl code behind with the `AutoGenerateColumn` event handler.

Running in the debugger I can see the e.PropertyDescritptor is type DataColumnPropertyDescriptor and can see its property of Column.Caption.

But at runtime I cannot find a way to access that `Column.Caption` directly, or cast the PropertyDescriptor as DataColumnPropertyDescriptor (internal sealed class).

```cs
private void dgProviderValues_AutoGeneratedColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    var pd = e.PropertyDescriptor as PropertyDescriptor;
    //e.Column.Header = pd.Column.Caption;
}
```

How can I get at the `DataColumnPropertyDescriptor` properties?

If that is not possible, any suggestions how to set column names in the `DataTable`/`DataColumns` that are accessible when rendering the `DataGrid`?

PS this is what I can see in the debugger when hovering over the value of pd:
[image]

Comment: Can't you store a reference to the `DataTable` and access it in the event handler? The `DataColumnPropertyDescriptor` won't give you the value of the `Caption` property of the underlying `DataTable`. Where did you see this?

Comment: I am using Prism MVVM so wanted to attempt to follow the principles and solve this 'properly'.
The frustrating thing: looking in the debugger, I can see the value I want right there but cant access it in the program.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty trivial solution when I stopped fixating on PropertyDescriptor.

The event calls this helper method with parameter; sender as DataGrid

```
    private void myDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        e.GridAutoGeneratingFromTable(sender as DataGrid);
    }

    public static void GridAutoGeneratingFromTable(this DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e, DataGrid dg)
    {
        var pd = e.PropertyDescriptor as PropertyDescriptor;
        if (dg.ItemsSource is DataView)
        {
            var dt = dg.ItemsSource as DataView;
            var col = dt.Table.Columns[e.PropertyName];
            //set e.Column.whatever = col.property
        }
    }
```